# Performance issues with gunicorn + gevent Django

Tags: django, gunicorn, wsgi, gevent

I'm encountering performance issues with gunicorn+genevent that is consuming a significant amount of RAM after conducting a high-load test. Even when I return an empty view with just a "hello world" message, the RAM usage continues to remain high, causing other requests to get stuck. I suspect that there might be a cache-related issue causing this behavior. Is there a way for gunicorn to clean up its cache automatically to return resources to normal levels after a high-load situation?

I've configured gunicorn to use the formula `NUM_WORKERS = NUM_CORES * 2` and performed tests with both 1 worker and more workers, but the results were the same.

Here's the command I'm using to run gunicorn:

```
gunicorn config.wsgi:application \
        --workers $NUM_WORKERS \
        --timeout $TIMEOUT \
        --keep-alive 2 \
        --bind 0.0.0.0:8000 \
        --log-level=debug \
        --log-file=- \
        -k gevent
```

Could this issue possibly be unrelated to gunicorn? If so, how can I go about testing for memory leaks? Your assistance is greatly appreciated.